# UITableViewRowAction title as image icon instead of text

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want put the icon (image) instead of text in swipe actions in tableviewCell in Swift.

But i dont how to put the image instead of title text?

### My code is below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?  {

    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        // 2
        let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Share using", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Twitter", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

        shareMenu.addAction(twitterAction)
        shareMenu.addAction(cancelAction)


        self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    // 3
    var rateAction =    (style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "rate",im , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        // 4

        let rateMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Rate this App", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let appRateAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Rate", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

        rateMenu.addAction(appRateAction)
        rateMenu.addAction(cancelAction)


        self.presentViewController(rateMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    // 5
    return [shareAction,rateAction]
}
```

Can you someone pls help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are currently no public APIs for this customization. The only editable properties are the title string, the background color, button style and background effect. You will have to create a custom format or use a third party library

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38655903/4928945

Comment: Answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/46647562/7576100

Answer (score 53):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

- Use Unicode characters in your text, if it serves your purpose, However unicode characters are limited set.
- Use emojis provided that it serve your purpose.

This is how you do it in the code

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "\u{267A}\n Delete") { action, index in
        print("more button tapped")
        self.tableView(tableView, commitEditingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#ef3340")

    let apply = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "\u{2606}\n Like") { action, index in
        print("favorite button tapped")
        self.tableView(tableView, commitEditingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Insert, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
    apply.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    let take = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "\u{2605}\n Rate") { action, index in
        print("share button tapped")
        self.tableView(tableView, commitEditingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
    take.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#00ab84")

    return [take, apply, delete]
}
```

This is what I could achieve by above mentioned ways -

[image]

Comment: Legend! This most of the times beats all third party solutions. I've got a question though, do you know where to find flat (similar to what you used) style emojicons? I looked around, and any emojicon that apple also has is shown as 3d (same as when you type a message). Is there any way to make them flat or show the original style? Like this website? http://graphemica.com/search?q=report

Comment: I do not know anything else then the emojis already available in Xcode which you can insert by using ctrl+cmd+space, since in this list most of them are 3d I prefer to use unicode character from site similar to what you have pointed. So to answer Sorry I have no idea how to make the emojis flat. :(

Comment: lol :) I didn't know that you can access them so easily! I looked all over the internet!! I think I'll do the same and follow it! But I'll open a question just in case someone else knows it! I'll update here with the link. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Sure feel free to do that.

Comment: The question has been asked :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577378/how-to-use-flat-emojicons-with-xcode

Comment: This is not the icon for delete. It should be like dustbin.

Comment: LOL that is just an example :)

Comment: Hi AppsWise. If i want to apply gradient color instead of simple solid color then what should i have to do in this scenario ?

Answer (score 27):

In **iOS 11**, Apple provides a way to help us do that.
There are 2 functions you need to implement to swipe cell to left or right

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
```

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            // Call edit action

            // Reset state
            success(true)
        })
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "ic_delete")
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    }
```

If you want to apply it for **iOS < 11.0**, you can do it by a **tricky way**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "") { action, indexPath in
            // Handle delete action
        }
        (UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIView.self])).setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_delete"), for: .normal)
        return [deleteAction]
    }
```

Comment: It works fine here, but below iOS 11, is there any way to apply this to multiple actions in one row? I've assigned two actions, but each one needs its one image.

Comment: @nontomatic Well, I think there isn't any way to do multiple actions in one row using 'tricky' way :(

Comment: When you are using **.jpg** in trailingSwipeActions... and get a blank white rectangle instead of the image, try to use a **.png** - that fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Not Swift, but for anybody else who lands here looking for a solution... I've got good results with the following simple subclass:

```
@interface GSBTableViewRowAction : UITableViewRowAction
@property UIImage *icon;
@property UIFont *font;
+ (instancetype)rowActionWithStyle:(UITableViewRowActionStyle)style title:(NSString *)title icon:(UIImage*)icon handler:(void (^)(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath))handler;
@end

@implementation GSBTableViewRowAction
+ (instancetype)rowActionWithStyle:(UITableViewRowActionStyle)style title:(NSString *)title icon:(UIImage*)icon handler:(void (^)(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath))handler
{
    if (title.length) title = [@"\n" stringByAppendingString:title]; // move title under centerline; icon will go above
    GSBTableViewRowAction *action = [super rowActionWithStyle:style title:title handler:handler];
    action.icon = icon;
    return action;
}

- (void)_setButton:(UIButton*)button
{
    if (self.font) button.titleLabel.font = self.font;
    if (self.icon) {
        [button setImage:[self.icon imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tintColor = button.titleLabel.textColor;
        CGSize titleSize = [button.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:button.titleLabel.font}];
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(titleSize.height/2 + 5), 0, 0, -titleSize.width); // +5px gap under icon
    }
```

The `rowActionWithStyle:title:icon:handler` is really just a convenience method - the 'secret sauce' is overriding the (private?) _setButton method [credit to Jayesh for this!].

This will give you an icon centered over the title, or just the icon alone if you leave the title nil. Unfortunately, you cant fiddle with the position of the title using `button.titleEdgeInsets`, like you can `imageEdgeInsets`, so best I can do is put the title immediately under the centerline (hence the '\n') with a small gap under the icon (5px above). Results look like

[image: row action with title + icon]

As a bonus, you can also change the title font, to say something smaller, by setting the new `font` property. eg the above 'Add' action was accomplished with

```
GSBTableViewRowAction *add = [GSBTableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal
                                                               title:@"Add"
                                                                icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Today-25"]
                                                             handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
                                                                 [self addToCalendar:self];
                                                                 [tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
                                                             }];
add.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote];
add.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor;
```

Caveat: _setButton is private API, so YMMV... We're all hoping Apple will expose a public API to do what they apparantly do in their Mail.app [sic]

Comment: Were Apple OK approving this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "      ") { action, indexPath in


        print("delete button tapped")
    }

    remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Delete")!)

    return [remove]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you explain how it works, and show in your code how to do it. Your current code does not cause an icon to show.

Comment: what size was the icon?

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, but it doesn't work. look at my swipe action : http://imgur.com/a/bw3O5

Comment: @Hogdotmac Please see my answer for iOS 11

Answer (score 3):

Check below working code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> \[UITableViewRowAction\]? {


            let backView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: tableView.frame.size.height))
            backView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239/255.0, green: 34/255.0, blue: 91/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

            let frame = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)


            let myImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: frame.size.height/2-20, width: 35, height: 35))
            myImage.image = UIImage(named: "delete_white")!
            backView.addSubview(myImage)

            let imgSize: CGSize = tableView.frame.size
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            backView.layer.render(in: context!)
            let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "           ") {
                (action, indexPath) in
                self.deleteCartItem(indexPath: indexPath )
                self.addWebtrendsForCart(path: "/Basket/EditBasket", description: "Edit Basket")
            }

             deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: newImage)
             return \[deleteAction\]
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Best answer ever!

Answer (score 2):

`trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath` works from iOS 11 only and is completely not customizable. You can change background color of a button, but you cannot add an image with you own colors even if you use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`.

I ended up using `MGSwipeTableCell`.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do the same thing and found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421894/uitableviewrowaction-image-for-title). It is a bit of a workaround.

Also, as seen from the iOS 9 betas, I think this will be possible, but I have not yet looked at the APIs.

Comment: thanks...i am checking with that answer now..i really appreciate your effort to put the answer on board..

Answer (score 0):

If you use answer of "Apps Wise"(https://stackoverflow.com/a/32735211/6249148), you can use this table for common unicode characters:
https://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/you-dont-need-icons-here-are-100-unicode-symbols-that-you-can-use

Or this one for ALL unicode characters:
https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character