# Swift - Tableviewcell delete icon custom

Tags: swift, uitableview

is it possibile to set the left icon (when deleting a row in tableviewcell) to a custom image?

[image: delete icon]

Thanks :)

Comment: Hope this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214735/5580393

Comment: you want always show that icon in there?

Comment: yes i just would like to have a custom image...

Comment: @Aditya is the left side icon not the confirmation button on the right

Comment: @Marco for left actions and icon you can once go through this: https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code into your `Your Controller`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let button1 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Your Title If You Want") { action, indexPath in
        print("button1 pressed!")
    }
    if let image = UIImage(named: "yourImage.png"){
        button1.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }
    return [button1]
}
```

Comment: thx... but this is for the right confirmation delete button.... i'm trying to change the left icon...

Comment: have you found your answer. if you have found then you can post your answer here so that other people can get help with your question.