# How to use flat emojicons with iOS

Tags: ios, unicode, character, emoji

I am trying to add an emoji / unicode character to the UITableViewRowAction title, so that I won't need to use third party libraries to add images.

Following the discussion I had [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32735211/1030580), I managed to add the emoji, but it's what Apple uses throughout the iOS, as you can see below:

[image: The actual UITableViewRowAction screenshot]

What I wanted to make is to have the same emoji, but having it in a different style. Maybe something like the image below that I got from [HERE](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%93%A3):

[image: Flat style emoji]

I have tried to use the xcode, and gone through the Unicode.org list [HERE](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf), but iOS only shows the stock emojis.

Is there a way of displaying the other styles of emoji / unicode characters?

Comment: A bit late...but there's also the possiblity of using variation selection characters.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75973271/314056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why some fonts use the coloured glyphs and some use the flat version but if you try some different fonts you will find some are flat!

For example, try Arial.

`[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14]`

Comment: Thanks I finished the project and ended up using just text. But I tried it and with a little trial-and-error it can work.