# Force iOS to Render Unicode Symbol as Flat / Text

Tags: ios, unicode, glyphicons

The iPhone is now automatically turning 2D unicode symbols into 3D emojis! For example:

[image]

I need the unicode to render in the traditional black-and-white glyph format. And, I can't easily replace the Unicode symbol with an image because this is happening in the editAction of a UITableView row. Hence the unicode:

// My struct for quick reference to symbols
struct cellEditActionIcons {
    static var upArrowSymbol = "\u{2191}"
    static var checkSymbol = "\u{2713}"
    static var deleteSymbol = "\u{2715}"
}

Now I need to find a way to force the unicode symbol to stay in flat style of a glyph format. I've found other people with the same problem, but no clear iOS solution yet ([SimilarIssue1](http://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/), [SimilarIssue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip)). Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable by adding unicode variation selector characters.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `&#x2764;` | ❤ | Indeterminate style |
| `&#x2764;&#xfe0e;` | ❤︎ | Force text style (VS-15) |
| `&#x2764;&#xfe0f;` | ❤️ | Force emoji style (VS16) |

For more info: https://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/