# Add Image To Button In UITableView's "editActionsForRowAt"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

A while ago I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004557/swipe-able-table-view-cell-in-ios9-or-swift-guide-at-least) on how to add more than the standard editActionsForRowAt "delete" button. Thanks to the posted answers, my app now has the 3-button swipe-to-edit functionality like below!

[image]

However, with iOS9 came pretty little icons to accompany the text... and now I have a new question, how do I get that functionality?

[image]

I've Googled many searches like "Add image to editActionsForRowAt" and found nothing helpful. If you have code, a tutorial link, or anything that could get me headed in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really should try to improve your google searching skill, try `uitableviewrowaction image` from your question's answer give a bunch of answers, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421894/uitableviewrowaction-image-for-title) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740884/uitableviewrowaction-title-as-image-icon-instead-of-text)

Comment: you have to create a custom cell for this kind of action .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the comments lead me to using unicode characters! Super helpful as they can be added to your normal string. Unicode characters include things like:

[image: Useful unicode character examples]
[image: Useful unicode character examples 2]
[image: Useful unicode character examples 3]

So all you do is pass a string with a unicode character, then a line break (\n), then your button title/text. So the basic syntax looks like:

```
title: "\u{1234}\n YourText "
```

For easy reuse (because I have multiple tables) I put the characters I wanted into a struct:

```
struct cellEditActionIcons {
    static var editAction_Arrow = "\u{2191}"
    static var editAction_Check = "\u{2713}"
    static var editAction_Delete = "\u{2715}"
}
```

Then you can create the buttons like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var doneBut = UITableViewRowAction (style: .normal, title: "\(cellEditActionIcons.editAction_Check)\n YourText" { action, index in
        //Do stuff
    }
    doneBut.backgroundColor = myColors.someColor
}
```